# How to delete unnecessary Ids of @JsonIdentityInfo?

Tags: java, json, hibernate, annotations

I have a problem with `@JsonIdentityInfo`. I'm getting two id in json file.

```
{
  "name" : "Tim",
  "@id" : 1, // fasterxml garbage
  "id" : 3,
  "company" : {
    "name" : "Microsoft",
    "employees" : [1], // garbage too
    "@id" : 2, // fasterxml garbage
    "id" : 3
  }
}
```

Here is my entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "company")
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.IntSequenceGenerator.class, property = "id")
public class Company implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;

    @Column
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "company")
    @Cascade(value = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Collection<Employee> employees;
```

How to delete unnecessary Ids?

UPD:

I'm using `com.fasterxml.jackson`

Answer (score 3):

This is an old question and you probably got the answer by now, but from reading it, it would seem your problem with additional ids comes from the generator you use.

`IntSequenceGenerator` will have Jackson generates auto-incremented ids, and you specified that you want them as `id` property (and as you already have an `id` property, I guess that's why Jackson produces `@id`). What you want is Jackson to use your existing `id` property, and for that you simply need to use the `PropertyGenerator`.

You will also need to use the `scope` attribute on the annotation as well as use it also on the `Employee` class, as you have two independent *id* sequences.

```
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property = "id", scope=Company.class)
public class Company {}

@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property = "id", scope=Employee.class)
public class Employee {}
```

This should produce for your example

```
{
  "name" : "Tim",
  "id" : 3,
  "company" : {
    "name" : "Microsoft",
    "employees" : [3],
    "id" : 3
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use JSON annotation like this to ignore them:

```
import org.codehaus.jackson.annotate.JsonIgnoreProperties;

@JsonIgnoreProperties({"id", "name"})
```

When creating JSON object, "id" and "name" will not be in the JSON object.